# What is physical in the principle of local gauge invariance?

Tags: particle-physics, gauge-theory, interactions

Modern theories of interactions in particle physics are gauge ones. I know how the gauge fields are introduced in equations ($D = \partial + A$). I just do not see any physical motivation in it. I am afraid it is done by analogy with QED and that's it. I conclude that it is not the only possible way of description of interactions. But maybe there is something essential that I am missing?

**EDIT:** As the main failure of gauge way of "introducing" interactions I can point out its intrinsically perturbative character. One cannot switch off **permanent** interaction without severe problems.

dbrane answered to that in comments "... you can treat gauge field theories non-perturbatively and still gather valuable insights ..."  Let us see. First question: With what does $A$ interact - with bare or real electron?

Comment: If the gauge bosons predicted by insisting on having local gauge invariance are consistently observed, why would you complain? More importantly, general relativity too is based on a local gauge invariance - do you find that unphysical too?

Comment: Gauge theories have severe conceptual and mathematical problems, why close eyes on it? "Let me advance as bad theory as a previous one"- is not a good motivation.

Comment: Can you list these conceptual and mathematical problems? And in each case please mention why you think these problems are a result of imposing local gauge invariance (which is natural if you accept the Equivalence Principle) and not because of something else.

Comment: Tp dbrane: Yesterday I borrowed some money from you for one night and today I say it was not me who borrowed money but a bare particle. So I owe you nothing. Is it OK with you?

Comment: Seems to me that this is a poor example of gauge invariance. Observables are not supposed to change under gauge transformations. amirite?

Comment: @Vladimir: No, it is not OK with me because analogies make no sense when you mix one situation with another.

Comment: To Cilin K: it was not a gauge transformation example but that of conceptual problem. We start with real particles in mind and then we declare them bare, unobservable, for the sake of saving the bad interaction Hamiltonian dictated with the "gauge" approach.

Comment: To dbrane: infinite corrections is a sign of a bad formulation, let's not blame the mother Nature for our "educated" guesses.

Comment: @Vladimir: you are again discussing renormalization. This has nothing to do with gauge theory per se. I suggest you either ask this as a separate question or else drop the subject altogether.

Comment: I just answer questions of my correspondents, Marek. There are other ways of making theory divergent, I agree, but I am sure that those divergences and conceptual problems are precisely due to blind guessing in the theory constructing. In particular, in gauge approach there is nothing physically motivated, on the contrary - there are things inadmissible in theoretical coinstructions but it is another subject.

Comment: @Vladimir: You didn't answer any of my questions. Like Marek said, you keep going into renormalization. I asked whether you find the local GI of relativity to be unphysical. I also asked you to mention conceptual problems arising from imposing local gauge invariance.

Comment: Dbrane, I am not good at GR and I do not like its self-collapsing feature. If it is a gauge theory, all the worse to this principle. As the main failure of gauge way of "introducing" interactions I can point out its intrinsically perturbative character. One cannot switch off permanent interaction without severe problems. Try to build the atomic wave function by the perturbation theory where the whole interaction potential 1/r is treated as perturbation, for example.

Comment: @Vladimir: You have an unhealthily dogmatic attitude to gauge invariance in my opinion. In GR, local gauge invariance is just a statement of the Equivalence principle - that you can *locally* transform to flat space coordinates, something you'd naturally want to do for purely physical reasons (and because the mathematical object of a manifold is perfectly suited for this). This is really the only reason it is a gauge theory - so if you think that it's bad that GR is a gauge theory, you're messing with the Equivalence principle. Good luck with that.

Comment: @Vladimir: ...Contd. Gauge invariance in quantum field theories is just a natural extension of this philosophy for the phases of wavefunctions. That's how I see it and to me it seems to produce miraculous results. Also, your objection that gauge interactions are perturbative (if that is an objection at all) is also not valid since you can treat gauge field theories non-perturbatively and still gather valuable insights.

Comment: The equivalence principle is used to introduce the Riemann space-time, not a "gauge" field. Electromagnetic field carries energy momentum unlike a propagating metric "wave". Well, gravity description is not the subject of my question.

Comment: @Vladimir: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_gauge_theory#General_relativity

Comment: "...you can treat gauge field theories non-perturbatively and still gather valuable insights..." No. How do you treat the quantized electromagnetic field non perturbatively in QED? With what does it interact - with bare or real electron?

Comment: I'm downvoting this.  Questions that are phrased bizarrely or obviously some sort of simple trick to promote some idiosyncratic viewpoint is an example of something I think this board wants to avoid.  Further, you can have interactive theories that are not gauge...

Comment: Look, dbrane, what if I have an equation non-invariant under some variable changes? Does it prevent me from making these variable changes? Especially if they are separated variables and help me solve the problem?

Comment: @Vladimir: I suggest you read Warren Siegel's Fields http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912205 esp. the section on gauge invariance in GR from Pg 587 on. I am not claiming that you can do everything in QFT non-perturbatively - that would clearly be far from the truth.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/5453/revisions shows that the EDIT in the main question do not complement nor address the question, it is just a discussion point. So I downvote! And it is a pity because it was a very good question, forcing people to go back to the history of physics in 1950s, Pauli look at EM gauge, then YM, then a visit to KK. And dont forget all these "gauge of the first kind", "of the second kind", "global", "local", etc...

Comment: And I really dont like downvoting! http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414/can-voting-anonymously-and-without-comment-lead-to-consensus-science

Comment: @Vladimir, I'm sure you're trying to convey some profound thoughts, but I see none here. And I don't think language is the issue this time. If you want to make an attempt at bringing down a paradigm (say that of "gauge invariance") you proceed by first pointing out its inconsistencies. Here you do no such thing. Saying something is "not physical" doesn't cut it. Your ideas and language need sharpening and moderation if you want to retain any credibility on this forum.

Comment: Thanks, Deepak Vaid, for your valuable advice. You are right nut it is not the whole truth. Another part of the truth is that many people ascribe me things I am not after. For example, conveying "profound thoughts". Yes, I have my own opinion and it is natural to use it in discussions but here it is not considered as "profound thoughts" and I am asking questions to get answers first of all. "Bringing down a paradigm" is not my goal, especially here, even though many accepted things are troublesome. (To be continued.)

Comment: If you analyze mechanical equations for a couple of particles, you will see that they have a clear physical sense: exchanges of energy, momentum, angular momentum between the particles. This is a physical model to follow. The "self-action" idea is troublesome but it is retained in physics since long ago (lack of better ideas). Why you forbid me to talk about it? Closing my questions is forbidding discussions. I, as an author of another approach, am very interested in learning different opinions here. I do not have any problem with gauge invariance. I have big problems with you censors here.

Comment: @vladimir, I like discussions too, but that isn't what this site was designed for if you look at the faq: "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here"

Comment: John, I am asking concrete questions here to learn answers. If some answer is not satisfactory, I re-ask and this is kind of discussion. In fact, I am collecting opinions. But many people are not loyal to me - that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You sure are having battles here, Vladimir! I find myself, however, having moderate sympathy with this particular question.

I think your comment, “*I just do not see any physical motivation in it. I am afraid it is done by analogy with QED and that's it.*” can be seen as a large part of its own answer. When we say that something is "Physically Motivated", I take this to mean that a plausible argument can be given for using, in a new situation, a generalization of a mathematical model that has previously been used successfully as a description for Physical phenomena. The form of a "plausible argument" is not given a priori, it's just a question of what Physicists as a group find plausible. Plausibility has an acid test, which is whether a given Physicist thinks an idea for a new class of mathematical models has enough promise that they *spend their own time* developing the mathematics and its relationships with experiment. All that said, QED is physically successful, and enough Physicists found it plausible to consider generalization to non-Abelian gauge fields that, over the course of 15 years, from the mid-1950s to 1972, say, with perhaps a few hundred people working on them, a new, moderately empirically successful class of mathematical models was constructed. The analogy with QED is significant, but it's the arguments for why someone in 1955 might think intensively about such models that I think you're not paying enough attention to. Those arguments are still known in the community, and they play out in various ways in the comments on your question and on your comments, but I think it's fair to say that they are not very *clearly* elaborated. There is no *axiomatic* QCD, that lays out both the mathematics and why it's especially natural as a Physical model, for a Physicist to point to, for example.

Underlying all your questions, answers, and comments, however, is your railing, as I see it, against renormalization. 40 years ago, you would have been in company with very eminent Physicists, but today the game has largely  moved on. People do talk loosely about bare and real electrons as you do, but the principal modes of discussion are now in terms of the renormalization group and the surrounding mathematics, which is well enough constructed as mathematics that as far as I can tell most Physicists are content with it, and almost all Physicists are content to calculate with it. As far as I've seen, models for real, shielded particles are relatively ad-hoc, and in any case, and insofar as they are not ad-hoc, are ultimately so grounded in the Taylor series mathematics of Feynman diagrams and the renormalization group approach that they are essentially not a new approach.

All sorts of moves are being made, both in the system and on the periphery, to tighten up the mathematics more, or to construct new non-perturbative methods, but they will *remain* peripheral for most Physicists until an approach is constructed that is significantly better as mathematics than the renormalization group approach, which seems more explanatory, and which is, additionally, more usable in an engineering sense than the renormalization group approach. I think it's significant that the renormalization group approach is more-or-less usable as *engineering*, but I think it's clearly enough not easy *enough* to use the renormalization group approach as engineering that a replacement for this way of thinking and constructing models will emerge in due course. I conclude, therefore, that I agree with you when you write “*I conclude that it is not the only possible way of description of interactions*“, but the hard issue is how to construct something that is better, preferably *significantly* better. Gotta do the math, and it's gotta be good math, but, harder, because it requires a certain kind of simplicity that we'll only recognize when we see it, it's gotta be good for use as engineering as well.

Best Wishes, Vladimir!

Peter.

Comment: Peter, I have a toy model with a very simple math. One can use practically the same equations as in QED but with other their meaning. In my model the real electron is "large and soft" (quantum mechanically smeared) and photons are just its elementary excitations. The most "difficult" thing is a concept of a "compound" electron. But as soon as we agree that the electron is permanently coupled with its quantized electromagnetic field (the exact QED equations say so), it is easy to accept a slightly different physical construction (in which the electron is coupled non perturbatively).

Comment: To me, a *toy* model isn't OK to face off with a big mathematical system like QFT, even if it might give a few people some feeling for how to construct a big enough alternative mathematical system. It needs a class of models that people can more-or-less comprehend as a whole system of thought, but that is still large enough that we feel able to model almost anything we might come across. We have to believe it will work. It must give enough insight to allow us to construct a first model, and we have to construct methods for refining those models. I think it needs very carefully chosen math.

Comment: To go at the *content* of your comment, if you're using the same equations as QED (or nearly), that sounds no different from other people's ways of talking about and modeling shielded particles. There are such ideas in the literature. To me, the problem is to construct new math, not to construct new interpretation. "Quantum mechanically smeared" is too vague --you need more precision--; if it's QED math, is it a quantized field? QED can be interpreted to be about an electron field interacting with an EM field, no particles, but with subtle discrete structure. No new math in that, though.

Comment: My electron is not "shielded" but "smeared". Somewhat like in atom - you have a "cloud" instead of a "point". Yes, we need correct interpretation, then the math is easy to apply. In my model one cannot "switch off" the quantized EMF generated by the electron - it is its essential feature and is provided by construction. An external field (sourced with the other charges) can be switched on like $D = \partial + A_{ext}$ but not the proper EMF. That's the difference. Of course, it is not in the state of the art yet but in course of "slow developing". The main difficulty is to find funding for it.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I thought that a perfect example and motivation for gauge fields is the electromagnetic field (the classical one). Isn't that a very good physical motivation!

Comment: CED (as well as QED) is not self-consistent, don't forget it.

Comment: So! CED (as well as QED) is very successful as a physics theory. That seems enough to me for motivation.

Comment: No, you do not use runaway solutions. You use an approximation because the exact solution is not physical. And that approximation is not the original theory. So you do not have a theory. Or you have unsuccessful theory.

Comment: When you say that classical electrodynamics is not self-consistent, are you referring specifically to issues surrounding point particles? Classical dynamics with nonsingular charge distributions is self-consistent, as far as I know.

Comment: To Ted Bunn: yes, all plasma physics uses smooth charge distributions, I know that. Yes, I speak of a single point-like charge model issues.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it was done by analogy with QED. If QED works that way why shouldn't other theories too? Naturally it's not this simple and it took time to make sense of other gauge theories but nevertheless it turns out that it works which is actually the only thing that matters.

Now, there is certainly no reason why it should be so. Also, by the very definition of gauge invariance of redundant degrees of freedom, you are free to fix the gauge and forget about gauge theories altogether if you are able to write down your Lagrangian in some other way.

So, in my opinion, there are only two reasons why one would introduce gauge invariance:

1. metaphysical one: it's a beautiful theory and the requirement of locality is definitely appealing as well (in the same way people liked moving from instant-action theories to local theories)
2. practical: it simplifies things *a lot*; both conceptually and computationally. Instead of looking for interaction given by arbitrary terms, you can just specify your field content and the group it's transforming under and you're done. The rest is routine (haha) work of verifying whether theory works.

Comment: Thanks, Marek, for your answer. So there is no real physical motivation to do so, it is just a blind guess. That's what is not good.

Comment: Vladimir, I wouldn't call that a "blind guess". My be a very educated guess?

Comment: Without physical motivation? No, it is a blind guess for sure! Or artificial intelligence guess, if you like ;-).

Comment: Yes, a very educated guess. And one that turned out very nicely too. Although, truth be said, the theory was first tried as $SU(2)$ for strong interactions which didn't work at all. Only much later it was realized that $SU(3)$ was the right group. Also, there are lots of other "problems", e.g. with introducing mass, that needed to be overcome. But in conclusion I'd say that it was very nice theoretical work that paid off. I don't understand @Vladimir's sentiment at all. Perhaps he's not familiar with all the successes of Standard Model yet...

Comment: SU(3) turned out better for classification of particles, I agree, but to introduce interactions? No, it is a different topic. I see one patch on another and a fanatic belief in our intellectual power whereas the physics task is different - follow experiments first of all.

Comment: @Vladimir: I of course meant colorful $SU(3)$ not the flavorful one. If you haven't heard about quantum chromodynamics and all the things it predicted (and which have been confirmed by experiment) you can start educating yourself e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics#Experimental_tests

Comment: You see, Marek, first you advance a theory and then you make experiments. So you see experimental data via the pattern of your theory, you are engaged already. Next, if something is possible to fit to experimental data, then it is used as a pretext to justify your guess. It is physics upside down. Physics must be as criminalistics - without emotions, biases, etc., without right to canonize errors.

Comment: @Vladimir: I don't know what you are talking about. If you think you have a proof that QCD is inconsistent with experiment then your are free to publish a paper about that. I am sure you will be very famous. If on the other hand you don't have such a proof and all your talk is just emotional nonsense stemming from not understanding the theory, I'd suggest you stop right there. In any case, I won't react to your comments unless you respond with some genuine physics, not emotional crap...

Comment: I am trying to distinguish a reasonable approach from self-fooling. As far as I can see, there is no physical motivation for such constructions so I do not buy it with its bare particles and patches in form of counter-terms. Do not tell me that this is the way it should be, Marek.

Comment: @Vladimir: the physics is not about motivation. Physics is about agreement with an experiment. If the theory agrees with experiment then it's completely irrelevant whether it has green skin, fourteen eyes and three legs. Or whether it obeys gauge invariance. It turns out that theories that *do* obey it are confirmed by experiment. That's the only motivation one needs. The other reasons (simplicity and beauty) are secondary. As for the counter-terms, I am not arguing with you about that. I know your feelings about renormalization and suffice it to say that I don't share them ;)

Comment: Marek, there might be many theories that agree with experiments. So why canonize one way of many, not the best one?

Comment: @Vladimir: so you have an alternative to Standard Model that agrees with experiment? And it's also mathematically better than Standard Model? Then by all means publish; the Nobel prize is inevitable.

Comment: I am not seeking fame, Marek, but answers to physical questions.

Comment: @Vladimir: no you are not. Physical questions are all answered by Standard Model. I agree that the theory *could* be nicer but we don't have anything nicer. And what we have works good enough and agrees with experiment. That's why I don't understand you. As long as we have a theory that produces correct predictions why do you care about the procedures that are used to arrive at those predictions? There is no such requirement that theory needs to be finite at every step of the calculation to be physical. It only needs to agree with experiment and Standard Model does that 100%.

Comment: Marek, any theory, any calculations need to be finite an meaningful, and it is what we achieve in the end. In the end the theory is a set of balance equations governing the occupation numbers. As such, this set of equations has finite solutions, perturbative and exact, whatever, so we must find a way to get it without pretexts to violate logic and math.

Comment: @Vladimir do you have similar problems with ansatzes used in solving differential equations? those are similarly pulled out of thin air.

Comment: No, Spencer, I don't. Solving differential equations is not the same as advancing interaction models.

Comment: At any given time in history the collection of all measurements done by mankind will be finite. So in principle, there can be infinitely many theories that fit those measurements (think of interpolation). But we don't even have one yet. We have many theories each fitting a particular subset of the data.